# How to change woocommerce checkout button for payment gateway?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a custom payment gateway that is based on a javascript API. The button at checkout has to work like the paypal checkout button works which opens another window but I can't find a way to replace the button. Since the button is loaded by javascript and the html is just a place

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'custom_order_button_html');
function custom_order_button_html( $button ) {

    // The text of the button
    $order_button_text = __(' order', 'woocommerce');

    // HERE you make changes (Replacing the code of the button):
    $button = '<div id="custom_Checkout_Button"></div>'; 
}
```

I put this function in `function __construct` but it doesn't replace.

The scripts are loading appropriately. If I load the script through console its loading fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `add_filter`, you'll always need to return the content you would like to filter or modify. Therefore, in your case, the code would look like this below.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_html', 'custom_order_button_html');
function custom_order_button_html( $button ) {

    // The text of the button
    $order_button_text = __(' order', 'woocommerce');

    // HERE you make changes (Replacing the code of the button):
    $button = '<div id="custom_Checkout_Button"></div>';

    // Return the modified/filtered content
    return $button;
}
```

You can find more usage examples [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

Comment: Ok that was one of the problems so now it shows up but flashes and disappears. I'm doing this filter in the constructor and then calling the enqueue of the script.

Comment: So, i got it to work like I said but, considering my question you had the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was do an on change method linked here

[Change Pay button on checkout based on Woocommerce chosen payment method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405604/change-pay-button-on-checkout-based-on-woocommerce-chosen-payment-method)

and used another jquery call to reload the script that I needed and it works like a charm.

If there is a right/better way to do this put it as an answer and I will accept.